# Error: mkdir ... The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows, go, prometheus

I am using `postgres_exporter` for `prometheus`, and when I am trying to run it it shows me an error:

> Error: failed to run "go-bindata -pkg=assets -o assets/bindata.go -ignore=bindata.go -ignore=.*.map$ -prefix=assets/generated assets/generated/...: exec: "go-bindata": executable file not found in %PATH%"
>   exit status 1

I realised that I had the wrong library of go-bindata installed. So after I installed the other one, error has changed to :

> Error: mkdir C:\Users\StarTech\go\src\github.com\wrouesnel\postgres_exporter\bin/C:: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   exit status 1

This is the link of `postgres_exporter`:
[postgres_exporter](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter)

First i type these commands:

```
go get github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
cd path/src/github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
go run mage.go
export DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://login:password@hostname:port/dbname"
./postgres_exporter <flags>
```

Also i am using `run` command instead of `export` since I'm on Windows.

And error happens when I type command `go run mage.go docker`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `go-bindata`:

```
go get -u github.com/tmthrgd/go-bindata/...
```

Comment: I tried it and after I typed it, it closed my command line. After that tried again that `go run mage.go docker` command but still the same

Comment: What's the output when entering "go-bindata" in your terminal?

Comment: If "go-bindata" isn't available, you should adjust your PATH to include the GOPATH binary directory:

`export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH`

Then try running "go-bindata" again.

Comment: just tried `set PATH=C:\Users\StarTech\go\src\github.com\jteeuwen\go-bindata` and still the same.

Comment: I guess i had the wrong version of go-bindata. I just installed the one you provided here. And the error changed to : `Error: mkdir C:\Users\StarTech\go\src\github.com\wrouesnel\postgres_exporter\bin/C:: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
exit status 1`